# Where does minikube deploy pods

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I was trying to use `minikube` for local deployment. But I couldn't figure out where exactly minikube deploy container. 
From what I understand `minikube` is a virtual machine that is completely different machine from host except they share resources. So when we deploy any container it should be deployed in `minikube vm` and not in host machine.
But when I started minikube with

```
sudo minikube start --driver=none --apiserver-ips 127.0.0.1 --apiserver-name localhost
```

Then I deployed my container through kubernetes.
After executing my `docker ps` command I can see them in my local machine.

```
fb41c2836a70        2f26ec35a739          "/bin/bash -ce someApp"  23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes k8s_someapp-7cbc9c4c87-lrrpm_default_d50b97bc-5200-404d-ad33-0d235d647614_0
a5faa3ec7539        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2  "/pause"                 23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes k8s_app-7cbc9c4c87-lrrpm_default_d50b97bc-5200-404d-ad33-0d235d647614_0
e175dbd7b6ea        207456039af0          "/bin/bash -ce cmd"      53 minutes ago      Up 53 minutes k8s_appd-69585dc55c-f7k4d_default_a6619c13-7341-4ca3-9dee-ee26b8fd0b2a_1
```

What is going on here I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minikube is NOT a virtual machine, minikube is a cli tool,

minikube starts a VM with k8s installed and running. By specifying `--driver=none` you are sying: "I don't want to use any vm driver", and so minikube won't use any driver and just start k8s on your host.

If you want to start a k8s in a VM you need to use a VM driver. From `minikube start --help`:

> --driver='': Driver is one of: virtualbox, vmwarefusion, kvm2, vmware, none,docker, podman (experimental) (defaults to auto-detect)

If you want to use virtualization, use one of the supported drivers.

Which one? Virtualbox is free and available for most platforms. kvm2 is linux only. Docker is not a VM but a container isolation platform.

Quick google search showed me this link: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/.
Check it out to learn more about supported drivers.

Comment: But there is some sort of virtualization involved right... Because I was able to deploy multiple container using same port. and I was not able to access that port directly I had to use port forwarding for that. Is that also expected behaviour?

Comment: The "virtualization" you are tallking about is called docker, and its not virtualization per se. Containers are not VMs. And speaking of container networking, yes, this is expected behaviour. If you want to know more, read about [kubernetes network model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#the-kubernetes-network-model).